# How do you run commands in a ASP.NET Core Framework app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, asp.net5

In a dnxCore project you can run the commands in you project.json file using "dnx command-name" How do you do that for a net461 project? If you try and run it with dnx it says the framework version in wrong. It Seems super simple but I can't figure it out or see any documentation about it.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: the command dnx has been removed and replaced with the command dotnet http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringTheNewNETDotnetCommandLineInterfaceCLI.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but using that how do you specify one of your commands? I can't see anything about it? It just seems to run on the default port and address

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dotnet console application and use it as a dotnet command. You need to set the outputName in project.json. You find more details in this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/extensibility

Here is the sample project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "outputName": "dotnet-helloworld"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code

using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can execute dotnet pack and create nuget package, create a nuget.config file, mention the location of nuget package in the nuget.config and can be used in the tools section also directly from command line.

Here is two links which might help you.

1. http://dotnetthoughts.net/building-a-custom-dotnet-cli-tool/
2. http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-nuget-packages-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for. I want to run commands on ASP.NET 5 sites. Basically I want to be able to run the site with the kestrel or weblistener as you can for a dnxcore project with commands configured in the project.json file and calling them with "dnx web" etc

Comment: dnx is no more. It is replaced with dotnet command. And these links to create a command similar to dotnet run, like dotnet helloworld(your custom command)

Comment: But that's not running a target of a ASP.NET website. ASP.NET is still around as is kestrel